# Making a ImageJ .jar from command line

Tags: java, command-line, jar, imagej

I have modified a ImageJ source code and i have compiled from command line, using the javac command, but Im trying to create a .jar file and I need help.

It is the first time that I'm trying to compile and create .jar from command line. When I created the .jar, I did the next command:

```
jar cf test.jar ImageJ/ij/*
```

**Directory "ImageJ/ij/" contains the compiled code.**

It doesn't fail but when I'm trying to execute the .jar It returns the error "Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from test.jar". When I execute a .jar I always do "**java -jar file.jar**" but, in this case, It doesn't work.

If I execute "**java -cp test.jar ij.ImageJ**" (ij.ImageJ is the Main Class) It works but I need to execute a macro in Batch mode and... It fails.

```
java -cp test.jar ij.ImageJ -batch ../MacrosIJ/helloWorld.ijm
  Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException: 
  No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation  which requires it.
  ...
```

If I create the .jar in Eclipse It works perfectly, **Can someone explain what i am doing wrong?**.
If someone can help I will be grateful. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended way to [build ImageJ from source](http://imagej.net/Source_code#Building_from_source) is using [Maven](http://imagej.net/Maven):

```bs
git clone https://github.com/imagej/ImageJA.git
mvn
cd target
java -cp ij-1.50.jar ij.ImageJ
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but... I cant do it, I'm working on a supercomputer at my university for ssh access and i have not the maven tools... i would need to talk with the administrator.

Comment: @SolidusAbi but you could do it on your local machine with maven and then transfer the built jar file. Or if your sysadmin won't install maven system wide (which is understandable), then you can build from source yourself and install on your home directory.